# SQL: Left Join with three tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, left-join

I have three tables

```
Products (idProduct, name)
Invoices(typeinvoice, numberinvoice, date)
Item-invoices(typeinvoice, numberinvoice, idProduct)
```

My query has to select all the products not selled in the year 2019. I can use a function to obtain the year from the date, for example year(i.date). I know that the products that don't appear in the Item-invoice table are the not selled products. So I have tried with this two codes and obtain a good output.

```
   SELECT p.name
   FROM Products p
   EXECPT
   SELECT ii.idProduct
   FROM Item-invoices ii, Invoices i
   WHERE ii.typeinvoice=i.typeinvoice
   AND ii.numberinvoice=i.numberinvocice
   AND year(i.date)=2019
```

And the other code use a sub-query:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM Products p
WHERE p.idProduct NOT IN 
            (SELECT ii.idProduct
            FROM Item-invoices ii, Invoices i
            WHERE ii.typeinvoice=i.typeinvoice
            AND ii.numberinvoice=i.numberinvocice
            AND year(i.date)=2019)
```

The answer is how can i use the left join command to have the same output. I've tried with

```
SELECT p.name
FROM Products p 
LEFT JOIN Item-invoices ii ON
            p.IdProduct=ii.idProduct
LEFT JOIN Invoices i ON
            ii.typeinvoice=i.typeinvoice
            AND ii.numberinvoice=i.numberinvocice
WHERE year(i.date)=2019
AND ii.idProduct IS NULL
```

I know this is wrong but can't find the solution

Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it's "wrong" (besides the spelling typos).  Nor am I sure exactly what you're trying to do.  But you seem to be on the right track.  Look here for more examples/more explanation: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-left-join/

Comment: SQLite does not have a YEAR() function. Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to move the condition on the invoice date to from the `from` clause to the `on` clause of the `join`.

Conditions in the `WHERE` clause are mandatory, so what you did actually turned the `LEFT JOI` to an `INNER JOIN`, which can never be fulfilled (since both conditions in the `WHERE` clause cannot be true at the same time).

```
SELECT p.name
FROM Products p 
LEFT JOIN Item-invoices ii ON
            p.IdProduct=ii.idProduct
LEFT JOIN Invoices i ON
            ii.typeinvoice=i.typeinvoice
            AND ii.numberinvoice=i.numberinvocice
            AND i.date >= '2019-01-01'
            AND i.date <  '2020-01-01'
WHERE ii.idProduct IS NULL
```

Note that I changed your date filter to a half-open filter that operates directly on the stored date, without using date functions; this is a more efficient way to proceed (since it allows the database to use an existing index).

Comment: As I offer in my answers, I also like to see others too.  Good clarification on WHY something did not work.  Helps others learn in context of their work and how to improve for future.